# Node.js My XML is not reading my XSLT

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

My Node.js follows this format.

```
if(req.method =="POST"){ refineXML(req, result =>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Context-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.write(result);
    res.end();
  });
};
```

The refineXML code is a simple method that takes in an encoded xml string, decodes it, removes the id, and then sends it back to the user. When I console.log the result, the answer is in promper xml format. However, I can't figure out how to link it to my XSL document. My XSL document currently lies under my project->WebContent->XSL

My Console keeps printing out

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(asyncId)' of null

whatever that means while my firefox says

> Error Loading stylesheet:The TLS handshake finished for ...
>   http://localhost:3000/my.xsl

Answer (score 0):

What does the stylesheet declaration look like in your xml document?

should look something like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="my.xsl"?>
```

the href should be a relative path so if your xml is at my project->WebContent then the PI would be:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="./XSL/my.xsl"?>
```

technically the leading ./ isn't needed but I find it aids clarity

Comment: My stylesheet declaration in the xml file is  **<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my.xsl"?>** My my.xsl is directly under the WebContent directory.

Comment: Where is it in relation to your XML file? if your XML is generated then you’ll probably need to make the path to the XML file absolute or find out how your XML processor resolves heeds